# Rails + Friendly ID: Have some paths use the numerical ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, friendly-id

I have a Rails application that uses the `friendly_id` Gem.

Using Friendly ID works well.

However, there are some paths in the backoffice where I do not want to use the Friendly ID slug in the URI, as it is not possible to use the same scopes as in the front-end.

e.g. I have an article that can have multiple versions. On each *blog* on the front, another article version is shown. Therefore, I can use `@blog.articles.friendly.find(params[:id])`. However, in the backoffice, I have pages where people can edit such a version, which is **not** nested under a Blog (because it is possible for a version to change blog using the form). Therefore, article versions that have the same slug as an earlier one will become inaccessible.

How can I instruct `friendly_id` and/or the Rails URL helper to not use the slug for these paths, but just use the good old numerical ID instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Article` model, add `finders` options to `friendly_id` attribute

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  friendly_id :name_of_article, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
  ...
end
```

In this case, whatever the `params[:id]` is, numerical id or slugs, you should still be able to get the article by `Article.find(params[:id])`.

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Hope it helped!

Comment: The problem is, that at some point there might be two Articles with the same slug. Which is expected behaviour, because they are scoped on `Blog`. e.g. `friendly_id :name_of_article, use: [:slugged, :history, :scoped], scope: :blog`. However, my articles on the back-end are not scoped on blog, so I would like to keep using the numerical IDs there.